# When creating a dictionary from a textfile, how do i add a newline to the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If the textfile is like this:

```
    1 aaaa
    2 bbbb
    3 cccc
    4 dddd
```

And i use this code in python:

```py
    def read_data(file_name):
        dictionary_reads = {}
        input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
        for line in input_file.readlines():
            key, value = line.strip().split(' ')
            dictionary_reads[key] = value
        input_file.close()
        return print(dictionary_reads)
```

I get:

```
'1': 'aaaa', '2': 'bbbb', '3': 'cccc', '4': 'dddd'
```

I would like to get this:

```
    '1': 'aaaa',
    '2': 'bbbb',
    '3': 'cccc',
    '4': 'dddd'
```

I know i removed the `\n` (newlines) with the .strip function, but if even if i don't, no newlines are made, the `\n` are just printed instead.

I hope it is not a crazy stupid question, i am quite new to python :)
Kind regards

Comment: The dictionary is *not text* in the first place. It's important that you distinguish between the thing itself, and a *textual representation of* the thing. It seems like your question is about how to *format* the display of the dictionary. In which case, please look at the `pprint` standard library module.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following line of code:

```
return print("{" + "\n".join("{!r}: {!r},".format(k, v) for k, v in dictionary_reads.items()) + "}")
```

instead of:

```
return print(dictionary_reads)
```

**Full Code**

```
def read_data(file_name):
    dictionary_reads = {}
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        key, value = line.strip().split(' ')
        dictionary_reads[key] = value
    input_file.close()
    return print("{" + "\n".join("{!r}: {!r},".format(k, v) for k, v in dictionary_reads.items()) + "}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Exactly what i wanted to know :D

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
return print("{" + "\n".join("{!r}: {!r},".format(a, b) for a, b in dictionary_reads.items()) + "}")
```

This formats the string and joins it before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired outcome by simply dumping your dictionary in JSON by using `json.dumps()`

```
return print(json.dumps(dictionary_reads,indent=len(dictionary_reads)))
```

Where, indent is the number of spaces per level and that would be equal to the length of dictionary in your case.

**Complete code**

```
import json
def read_data(file_name):
    dictionary_reads = {}
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        key, value = line.strip().split(' ')
        dictionary_reads[key] = value
    input_file.close()
    return print(json.dumps(dictionary_reads,indent=len(dictionary_reads)))
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much!